# How can I open an existing directory using RandomAccessFile in Java?

Tags: java, directory, randomaccessfile

I want to open a directory using RandomAccessFile. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`RandomAccessFile` cannot open directories. In Java, directories are processed using the types `File`, `Path`, `Files`, `Paths` and `FileSystem`.

What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I am going to have to make those changes.